# CSS Class is not working in Google Chrome, but working fine in IE and Mozilla. What I need to change so that it will work in all browser?

Tags: css, google-chrome

This is my sample code, I am using it for a text field to change its borders colour to blue, when the text field is in focous. It's working fine in IE and mozilla but not working in Google Chrome. Please help.

```
.inputTxtFld:focus {/* font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #000000;*/
        MARGIN: 0px;
        PADDING-TOP: 2px;
        PADDING-RIGHT: 4px;
        PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px;
        PADDING-LEFT: 4px;
        WEBKIT-BORDER-TOP: #00c0f0 1px solid;
        WEBKIT-BORDER-RIGHT: #00c0f0 1px solid;
        WEBKIT-BORDER-BOTTOM: #00c0f0 1px solid;
        WEBKIT-BORDER-LEFT: #00c0f0 1px solid;
        FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        FONT-SIZE: 11px;
        COLOR: #333;
        BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFFFFF;

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-WEBKIT-BORDER-TOP: #00c0f0 1px solid;
-WEBKIT-BORDER-RIGHT: #00c0f0 1px solid;
-WEBKIT-BORDER-BOTTOM: #00c0f0 1px solid;
-WEBKIT-BORDER-LEFT: #00c0f0 1px solid;

-MOZ-BORDER-TOP: #00c0f0 1px solid;
-MOZ-BORDER-RIGHT: #00c0f0 1px solid;
-MOZ-BORDER-BOTTOM: #00c0f0 1px solid;
-MOZ-BORDER-LEFT: #00c0f0 1px solid;
```

And for IE later:

```
BORDER-TOP: #00c0f0 1px solid;
BORDER-RIGHT: #00c0f0 1px solid;
BORDER-BOTTOM: #00c0f0 1px solid;
BORDER-LEFT: #00c0f0 1px solid;
```

Answer (score 2):

..or you could just do;

```
border: 1px #00c0f1 solid;
```

You don't need the Vendor Prefix as the CSS Border property is supported by all browsers..

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you need to specify a dash prefix for the webkit styles, like so:

```
-webkit-border-top: ...
```

Further, lowercase all of your css attributes.  Have some style, man!